# borrar valor en lista de diccionarios en python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

ando atascado con esto:
Tengo una lista de diccionarios y quiero borrar un valor que se introduzca por teclado, pero no lo consigo. Lo estoy intentando con .remove() pero me da error. Algun alma caritativa que pueda ayudarme?

```
usuarios=[{"Nombre":"Josep"},{'Nombre':'Claudio'},{'Nombre':'Isabel'},{'Nombre':'Sheila'}]
nombre=input("Introduzca el usuario que quiere eliminar: ")
usuarios.remove()
print(usuarios)
```

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje lo estás haciendo? Considera ponerlo en tu pregunta.

Comment: Si es verdad, se me paso ese pequeño detalle. Es en python

Answer (score 0):

Dado que tienes una lista de diccionarios deberemos recorrer cada elemento y acceder a la clave `Nombre`, esto es bastante fácil y se puede hacer de diversas formas

Una forma es con una comprensión de lista donde creamos una nueva lista con los elementos que cumplan la condición

```py
usuarios=[{"Nombre":"Josep"},{'Nombre':'Claudio'},{'Nombre':'Isabel'},{'Nombre':'Sheila'}]
nombre=input("Introduzca el usuario que quiere eliminar: ")
#creamos una lista con los diccionarios que cumplan la condición 
usuarios = [n for n  in usuarios if n["Nombre"]!=nombre]
print(usuarios)
```

Y la otra forma sería con un ciclo for normal

```py
usuarios=[{"Nombre":"Josep"},{'Nombre':'Claudio'},{'Nombre':'Isabel'},{'Nombre':'Sheila'}]
nombre=input("Introduzca el usuario que quiere eliminar: ")

for e in usuarios.copy(): 
    if e["Nombre"] == nombre: usuarios.remove(e)
```

Comment: Para evitar recorrerte la lista varias veces con .remove puedes crear una nueva lista e ir agregando los valores allí según si coinciden o no con el nombre de usuario ingresado. Es decir, usar el equivalente a una comprension de lista.

Comment: Hola Christian. Gracias por la respuesta pero me da el siguiente error usandio el FOR: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: No hay ningún error en el código de Christian. Copiaste bien sus códigos @Tomas?

Comment: Pensé en tu error, y a mi me parece que lo que contiene tu lista NO son diccionarios. No es obligatorio, pero podrías editar la pregunta y poner tu código original por favor?

Comment: Vale. Ya esta. Lo habia copiado mal. Muchas gracias a los 2 por la ayuda.

Comment: Es un placer c:

Comment: @DanteS. Me asusté al ver 6 notificaciones ._.

Comment: @Christian pobre xD ya me imagino como entraste a SO y viste ese 6 en la bandeja de entrada!

Comment: @DanteS. Presente 2 formas de hacerlo y una de ellas (la primera) es la compresión de lista en la cual se vana agregando elementos según la condición

Comment: @DanteS. Pensé que había hecho algo mal, pues respondí la pregunta cuando recién me había despertado y ni siquiera lo probé

Comment: @Christian lo se. Me refería a que el segundo código podría ser más eficiente sin usar remove: `usuarios2 = []

for user in usuarios:
    if(user["Nombre"] != nombre):
        usuarios2.append(user)`

Comment: Perdon por hacerte pensar eso. No hiciste nada mal nwn

Comment: @DanteS. ¿añadir una linea final  `usuarios = usuarios2.copy()` , como lo ves?

Comment: @TomyGijon Sinceramente lo veo innecesario, pues la nueva lista ya está guardada en usuarios2. Además puedes darle un alias a la misma lista con `usuarios = usuarios2`. Pero gracias igual por tu contribución c:

Comment: @DanteS. siempre quedo con esa duda, ahora la tengo resuelta Gracias

Comment: @TomyGijion no es que me moleste pero... por algo existe el chat